# Finding hidden parameters manually for XSS

Tags: penetration-test, xss, javascript, reflected-xss

I am researching about XSS and Google helped me a lot about learning like how to bypass XSS filters, POST and GET based XSS .

I am really curious to know how to find hidden parameters manually for XSS testing purposes.

Also can we find parameters by Google dorking? Or by viewing page source code? Also any tools that can be used for finding parameters?

Comment: Hello and welcome! What do you mean by "hidden parameters"? I'm not familiar with the phrase.

Comment: Developers don't want to show some parameters to client side. So they hide those parameters.

Comment: Do you mean *input type="hidden"* ?

Comment: @user11177344 I still don't understand. What do you mean by parameter? Query parameter like `?foo=bar` in the URL? And what do you mean by hiding it to the client side?